# My Timeline window is missing lots of controls

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, animation

I'm using CS6.

Can someone tell me how to display all the controls of the timeline window ?

Here's what mine looks like:

[image: http://www.contentamp.com/wp-content/themes/snm/images/Rebrand/Animations/MY_timeline.JPG]

All the demos / tutorials [show the timeline quite differently there:

[image: http://www.contentamp.com/wp-content/themes/snm/images/Rebrand/Animations/Your_Timeline.JPG]

Comment: Looks like there's a similar discussion over at the Adobe forums: [Do I have to upgrade to Photoshop CS6 Extended to edit videos?](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5084818). Not sure if any of that information is helpful, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to toggle between frame animation and timeline. In the lower left-hand corner of the palette — next to where yours says "Forever" — is supposed to be a little icon which sort of looks like a bar chart with a triangle on top. Click that. It will convert to the palette shown in the demo.

Why yours doesn't have that I can't say. Try clicking around and see what it needs to activate it.

**ETA I found it:** in the palette options fly-out, four up from the bottom, select "Convert to video timeline."

Comment: Lauren, I really can't find any settings that make the icon you talk about appear.  When you hover over the icon, is there a tool-tip that tells you what the icon is called ?

Comment: thanks for the update, but I can't see that option. I've uploaded an image so you can check that I'm looking in the place you described...  [My palette Options](http://www.contentamp.com/wp-content/themes/snm/images/Rebrand/Animations/TimelineOptions.JPG)

Comment: @wotney You are in the right spot, but it's not there. You probably have something weird going on with that specific document. Create a new document and try it with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you should have Photoshop extended so you can open all timeline features.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is accurate, do you have any source to back it up?